# formData is empty (while uploading it through XMLHttpRequest - pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest

I need to send along with my variable data also a blob file,
so i needed to switch from POST plain

```
 http1.send("var1=" + var1 + "&var2=" + var2 + "")
```

to **formData**.

But **formData** is totally empty, even when I output it to the console.
Here's my code.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("customer_id", customer_id)
formData.append("nume", btoa(nume))
formData.append("prenume", btoa(prenume))
formData.append("signature", blob, "signature.jpg");
.....

var phpscript = 'AJAX/ajax_save_form.php'
http1.open('POST', phpscript)
http1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http1.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(http1.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(http1.status == 200)
        {
            var ajaxMessage = http1.responseText    
            alert(ajaxMessage)

        } 
    }
}
http1.send(formData);

console.log(formData);
```

Here are some typical values for my variables :

```
customer_id = 4
nume = 'Bill'
prenume = 'Gates'
blob = .jpeg file
```

Can anyone track this for me ? Where am I wrong ?
I browsed the net for 20 different solutions and pages, and none can solve my problem.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Hi Adrian. It'll be kinda hard to help with this one unless we can see the values you are using for the form, like what `customer_id` is and where you are logging `formData`

Comment: I added what you requested....but I found my answer. Needed to remove the "setRequestHeader" alltogether ! :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormData` object needs to be sent as multipart/form-data, you set the content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
Remove the call to `setRequestHeader` and the correct content type will be set.

Comment: thank you ! this solved my problem ! million thanks :) I was trying to change the "content-type" but removing the "setRequestHeader" all together did the trick ! million thanks @Musa !

Comment: You can't set the proper content type because you would not know what to put as the boundary